# Retrieving options from Devise mailer method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to pass some extra info to the devise mailer method.  For instance I want to pass on info that the user is a photographer using ...

```
MyDeviseMailer.confirmation_instructions(@user, nil, photographer: true  )
```

I am having difficulty retrieving that information.  I have tried the following using opts

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
 @token = token
 @user = record
 @is_photographer = opts[:photographer]
 devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I added one simplification and one improvement:

- Using `super` to delegate the rest of the work back to devise's original implementation
- Using `opts#delete` to avoid having the opts value get set on the email header automatically (devise does that by default).

`app/mailers/my_devise_mailer.rb`

```
class MyDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
    helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
    default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        @is_photographer = opts.delete(:photographer)
        super
    end
end
```

Now, the view can use `@is_photographer`.

`app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb`

```rb
<% if @is_photographer %>
    <p>Welcome photographer <%= @email %>!</p>
<% else %>
    <p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>
<% end %>
```

Perhaps, a simpler alternative is to avoid creating your `MyDeviseMailer` all together and just put `is_photographer?` as an attribute reader or method on `User` directly and use it in the devise mailer template off of @resource.

`app/models/user.rb`

```
class User
    ...
    def is_photographer?
        ...
    end
    # or
    attr_reader :is_photographer?
    # or
    attr_accessor :is_photographer?
end
```

`app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb`

```
<% if @resource.is_photographer? %>
    <p>Welcome photographer <%= @email %>!</p>
<% else %>
    <p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>
<% end %>
```

Additionally, this option gives you the power to easily add extra attributes or methods on `User` and include their information in the mailer template provided they truly belong to the `User` model. For attributes that do not belong, the first option of customizing your own `MyDeviseMailer` will help. It is possible to combine both options too if there is a mix of user-belonging and non-user-belonging attributes.